# how to specify file name and close the info path form on custom submit button?

Tags: events, button, click, infopath

i have submit button in the form once i click it must ask to enter the file name and once i given it it must close the particular browser tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's fairly simple. You need to configure the submit data source where you point to the document library you want to submit your form to. After that you create your custom button and there you use rules:

1) Calculate file name and save it to a field in your main data source

2) Use submit using data source rule to save the form to Sharepoint document library, there you can use your file name field

3) Use close form rule

Answer (score 0):

As part of the advanced submit options you can specify that the form closes after submit.  not sure if that will close browser tab though as I generally use the infopath client.  As for asking for a filename, the file name of the form will usually be specified by some formula when setting up submitting to a sharepoint document library so that you get a consistent filename format.

if you wish to handle these your self with code then that is possible but I have not tried from a browser based form, only from the infopath client.